# Проблема с сессиями

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 3 страницы :

> 1.php
>
> 2.php
>
> 3.php

- На 1.php юзер вводит данные, они передаются на 2.php через скрытые поля
- На 2.php `session_start()` и заношу в сессии значения. Также на второй еще надо ввести логин и пароль, если логи уже зарегистрирован в БД, то тогда пользователя отправляют опять на 2.php.

Проблема в том, что если пользователя вновь переводят на 2.php. то сессия стирается.

Вторая проблема в том, что если даже я его не отсылаю и без всякой проверки, и прошу просто вывести из сессии что-то оно выводит, но также пишет

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   Y:\home\localhost\www\u\parent.php:2) in
>   Y:\home\localhost\www\u\parent.php on line 3

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сессия не стиралась надо делать либо массив значений( если надо чтобы их было несколько ), либо проверять на существование того либо иного значения перед тем как туда что-либо писать.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

header already sent выдает потому-что **session_start()** нужно писать в самом начале любого кода(если быть максимально точным то до вывода какой либо информации), у вас этого нет.

На всякий случай пример :)

```
// код.....
session_start();
// не правильно

session_start();
// код....
// правильно :)
```

Если же это не то, возможно **session_start()** вызывается несколько раз.

Comment: <?php
 session_start(); //3 строчка

Comment: Если же это не то, возможно session_start() вызывается несколько раз.

Answer (score 0):

headers already send by еще и из-за кодировки php-файла выскакивают, utf-8 without BOM в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

1. До "< ? p h p", в котором вызывается session_start() не должно быть ни одного 
   *байта*, это должно быть в самом начале файла
2. session_start() должно быть в самом начале каждого файла.